# What is the difference between "bicyclist" and "cyclist"?

Tags: phrase-usage

For example, if I was hit by a bicycle, should I tell the police a "cyclist" or "bicyclist" hit me. If either one, which one is more common in AmE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strictly speaking, *cyclist* includes someone riding a cycle with a number of wheels other than two:  unicycle, tricycle or quadricycle.

However, the use of *bicyclist* nowadays is not very common.  Unless of course there was a mixed group of bicyclists and tricyclists and you wanted to be specific.